# 'inet_ntoa' not declared error

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I'm tring to use inet_ntoa function
writing to following code:

```
printf("Got connection from: %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr.s_addr), cli_addr.sin_port);
```

Using the following includes:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

But, using g++/gcc I'm  always get the error:

> error: ‘inet_ntoa’ was not declared in this scope

If I'm comment that line, the code is just fine.

Running under Ubuntu12.04.

Can anybody tell me what I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Which compiler are you using ? I got your code compile fine on g++/gcc 5.1

Comment: OT: `sin_port` comes in network byte order. You want wrap the call into `ntoh()` to print the port number using (the more readable ;-) host byte order.

Comment: I compiled under g++ 4.6.3; @shrike

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man inet_ntoa` it appears you have to define `_BSD_SOURCE` before including the headers:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: I'm using Centos7 and didn't have to define _BSD_SOURCE - looks like I was just missing arpa/inet.h :)